# NULL value will be pasted on a non-spatial table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have a non-spatial table (PostGIS) in QGIS with one column only. Whenever I paste value on that table from data on Google Sheet or from Notepad, it will paste null value even it has an actual text value.

What is the proper way to copy and paste data/value on a non-spatial table?

This is the steps I did:

1. Open the Attribute Table of that non-spatial table and toggle edit mode
2. From Google Sheet, I just copy for example 3 rows with just numbers on it
3. Then I paste it on the Attribute Table
4. A prompt window will appear to "Fix Pasted Features" because I activate the "Enforce Null Constraint" and since the value pasted is null (even it has value on it)

Comment: PostGIS is a spatial type implementation in PostgreSQL. A nonspatial PostGIS table is a *non sequitur*.

Comment: It would help if you edited your original post to explain the exact steps you use to copy and paste. Screenshots would also help.

Comment: I added the steps I made as suggested...

Comment: The problem continues if the field is of character data type?

Comment: why is it a problem if the field is a character data type?
the source data is a character type even though the value is a number

actually if the source value is "abc" then paste it to that non-spatial table, it will detect as a null value... I just don't understand why